# Merge split backup in container

Tags: backup

I have a backup on my former hosting's container storage but it's split into 200MB parts [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZhYa.png)

So I can download the parts and when I do a `cat file-003` I do get some plain text in addition to the garbled binary it pukes out, meaning that is the right image as I can see some tables of a database I had backed up on the site.

So my question is, how do I join them parts together again and if I can do that, how do I go about launching them on another provider who also uses openswift?

Answer (score 0):

If they were split using the utility `split`, you can cat them back together thusly:

```
cat <filenamepattern> > <outputfilename>
```

I've done this with very large ISOs that were `split` into 2GB chunks (to fit inside old IE file size limitations like this:

```
cat product.iso-part* > product.iso
```